# Is it possible to count distinct Documents in MongoTemplate?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

Is it possible to somehow chain distinct(...) and countDocuments(...) in mongoTemplate.

Something like this

```
mongoTemplate.getCollection("foo").distinct("bar", Foo.class).countDocuments();
```

To keep in mind I will have a few million results, so I dont want to create a bottleneck in the jvm by getting all all distinct entities into an array and then getting the size of it. I rather want to get a number from MongoDB and dont bother JVM.

Comment: Instead of _countDocuments_ you can use `into(new ArrayList<Foo>()).size()`. That will give you the count.

Comment: The problem is, I expect a few million results that means that my array will bloat up in the JVM. Is it possible to get the size from MongoDB instead of getting a Size of an Array ?

Comment: is the use of mongo's aggregation pipeline allowed here? Can you give more information on the schema for your `bar` attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It is possible to get count of distinct documents using mongoTemplate.

Mongo shell query

```
db.foo.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: "$bar"
    }
}, {
    $count: "total"
}]);
```

Output of this query will be

```
{
    "total" : 8
}
```

To get this result using MongoTemplate:

```
GroupOperation groupOperation = Aggregation.group("bar");
CountOperation countOperation = Aggregation.count().as("total");
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(groupOperation, countOperation);

Document result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "foo", Document.class)
        .getUniqueMappedResult();
Integer total = Objects.nonNull(result) ? result.getInteger("total") : 0;
```

Comment: This is exactly what i need ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Last time I remember that I used the [Aggregation Pipeline Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) by which I grouped the collection(which will give you distinct values) and then use `count()` on top of it.

**For Example:**

```
Aggregation pipeline = newAggregation(
        group(fields("foo","bar")),
        group("_id.bar").count().as("distinctCount")
    );
```

Else use the following one liner:

```
return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation,Class.COLLECTION_NAME,BasicDBObject.class).getMappedResult();
// in this case make sure this function's return type is Integer or Long not int or long
```

NOTE: in this case, make sure the function's return type is `Integer` or `Long` not `int` or `long` as int and long are primitive data types and they do not contain null. However, in case, there is no data, the aggregation logic might return null hence the use of Long or Integer (object could be null)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mongo Aggrigate with $group.

```
db.foo.aggregate([{
  '$group': {
    '_id': '_id', 
    'count': {
    '$sum': 1
   }
  }]);
```

You will get:

```
{ "_id":"_id", "count":12}
```